# Odoo: Get Fields name on other Model and make it as Selection

Tags: python, odoo

I want to get the field names in a model to be an option in a selection field in another model. Is it possible?

```
class ExportEmplWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'hr.empl.exp.wizard'

    empl_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string="Karyawan")
    hr_field = fields.Selection(hr_field_choice, string="Pilih Kolom")


    def empl_to_exp(self):
        fields = self.env['hr.employee'].fields_get()
        hr_field_choices = []
        for key, val in fields.items():
            choice = (key, val['string'])
            hr_field_choices.append(choice)
```

I'm trying get fields  name on other model using:

```
sel.self.env['hr.employee'].fields_get()
```

The problem is, i don't know how to make it as selection options (multiple selection actually).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: show the code which you have tried

Answer (score 1):

As per [docstring for `fields.Selection()`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/fields.py#L1653)

> :param selection: specifies the possible values for this field.
>           It is given as either a list of pairs (`value`, `string`), or a
>           model method, or a method name.

Basically, the `selection` argument should work like the `compute` argument. And [code of `fields.Selection.get_values()`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/fields.py#L1727) confirms this.

So you should try something like this :

```
hr_field = fields.Selection(selection='empl_to_exp', string="Pilih Kolom")

def empl_to_exp(self):
    fields = self.env['hr.employee'].fields_get()
    return [(k, v['string']) for k, v in fields.items()]
```

You may have/want to use `getattr(v, 'string', 'DEFAULT_VALUE')` instead of simply `v['string']`. Fields should always have a string though.

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_selection_name(env, model, field, value):
    return dict(env[model].fields_get(field, 'selection').get(field, {}).get('selection',{})).get(value)

# usage

get_selection_name(request.env, 'sale.order', 'general_status', 'draft')  # 'Draft'
get_selection_name(self.env, 'sale.order', 'general_status', 'draft')     # 'Draft'
```

I use this!